# Access Domino server from a mobile app?

Tags: mobile, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

i want to develop a mobile app which should only be used internal in my company. My Chef want that the app should be able to show all the employees contacts, emails and calendar which in stored in the Domino server (we use Lotus Notes).
Since i have never worked with Domino server, i would like to ask if it's even possible to access the datas in Domino server from a mobile app or possible workaround to access the datas from a mobile app?

I will be thankful for every advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [IBM Domino Access Services (DAS)](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=api) or access Domino data per [URL/http](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ABOUT_DOMINO_URL_COMMANDS_4332.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at IBM Traveler server extension and the IBM Verse Client. These will allow all the access from mobile devices that you say you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.

One way to do it is to build your own REST API on the Domino server and call it from your mobile app. You probably need someone with Domino development skills for this, but there are still a few of us around.

You could also use DAS, as Knut suggests. I have heard some people recommending not to use it due to security issues, but I don't know what they are. I find it easier to write my own API, so I get exactly what I want, in exactly the format I need.